# Giving Key Error with Windows task scheduler when it works fine in terminal

Tags: python, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to automate a Python script. The script runs fine when I in terminal using `py C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\main.py`. It also works when I run it in PyCharm. But when I try to run it from task scheduler I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\main.py", line 235, in on_ready
    await scrape_data()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test\main.py", line 167, in scrape_data
    new_events = df.loc[~df['Key'].isin(previous_df['Key']) & ~df['Key'].isin(sent_events_df['Key'])]
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3761, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 349, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'Key'
```

I set up two tasks to test. One where it runs the command prompt and executes that command, and one where it runs the script directly. I tried basic sample programs to make sure it works and it does. I also removed it from the virtual environment and ran it directly in terminal and it works, so I think the dependencies are fine. I am running it with Administrator privileges. I don't understand why it would run normally but not from task scheduler. Is there anything I am overlooking?

Comment: Where does the data come from?  Are you literally running the task as the user "Administrator"?  The system users don't have access to the AppData folders of users.

Comment: The data is scraped from the internet. It keeps appending to a new csv which is serving as a temporary database. It is a VM and the only user I have set up is Admin.

Comment: OK, but when you create a Scheduled Task, the default user is the System account, which does not have access to your files.  Check the "Run As" fields in your Scheduled Task.